# Flexigrid table : how to add tooltip on column header

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I want to add tooltip on hover of flexigrid table column header. Different column with different tooltip content.

Flexigrid url : http://flexigrid.info/
GitHub url : https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid

I didn't get anything regarding same on google.

Answer (score 1):

Would this not work for you? Unless I'm misunderstanding..
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

From the jQuery link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-  ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a href="#" title="Anchor description">Anchor text</a>
    <input title="Input help">
  </p>
<script>
  $( document ).tooltip();
</script>

</body>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/JnrBZ/

Comment: No I am using flexigrid table in which column header comes from js file eg: https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/blob/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1):

flexigrid.js line 916 add

```
if( cm.title != undefined ) {$(th).attr('title', cm.title);}
```

In your colModel section under

```
$("#flex1").flexigrid({
colModel : [
{display: 'MyDC',title: 'My Data Column', name : 'mydatacolumn', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'center'}
]
});
```

You can then add a title: attribute.

Comment: bummi, thanks for editing my comment to look nice.  I am still trying to figure out how to do that.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
if( cm.title != undefined ) 
  {
     $(th).attr('title', cm.title);
  }
```

is working for me, but just on the top-right column header, not in other columns.